# Strange heap checker error in death test

Tags: c++, memory-management, googletest, googlemock

I have a problem with one of my googletest unittests that uses a mock object and a death test. This is a minimized code sample that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace ::testing;

class MockA {
  public:
    MockA() {};
    virtual ~MockA() {};

    MOCK_METHOD1(bla,int(int));
};


class B {
  public:
    B(MockA * a)
            : a_(a) {};
    void kill() {
        exit(1);
    }
    MockA * a_;
};

TEST(BDeathTest,BDies) {
    MockA * a = new MockA();
    ON_CALL(*a,bla(_)).WillByDefault(Return(1));
    B * b = new B(a);
    EXPECT_DEATH(b->kill(),"");
    delete a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from BDeathTest
[ RUN      ] BDeathTest.BDies

gtest.cc:27: ERROR: this mock object (used in test BDeathTest.BDies) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x7fe453c00ec0.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
[       OK ] BDeathTest.BDies (2 ms)
[----------] 1 test from BDeathTest (2 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (2 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

It seems like googlemock checks for left over mock objects on the heap right after the `EXPECT_DEATH` assertion, but deleting `a` before invoking the macro is obviously not a good solution, as `a` might be used in the function that's invoked. I would actually expect the check to occur at the end of the test suite deconstruction. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably the exit in the child process causes the program to terminate without deleting the mock object, but causes the mock object cleanup routines to do leak checking. I would try using abort() instead of exit

Comment: It actually works using `abort()`, although this does not help much, as I want to check for specific error codes in the production code.

Comment: I dont think the death tests are made for that, they should just assure that something crashes. Maybe you want to throw exceptions and verify that a certain exception is thrown?

Comment: In my understanding, that's exactly what they're meant for, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-googletestingframework.html?ca=drs-

Comment: note how they use assert_exit, not assert_death (or the expect variant)

Comment: According to the documentation: "The *_DEATH macros are convenient wrappers for *_EXIT that use a predicate that verifies the process' exit code is non-zero."
Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `a` will be leaked, you need to tell gmock about this:

```
TEST(BDeathTest,BDies) {
    MockA * a = new MockA;
    ON_CALL(*a,bla(_)).WillByDefault(Return(1));
    B * b = new B(a);
    Mock::AllowLeak(a);  // <=== Self-explanatory addition
    EXPECT_DEATH(b->kill(),"");
    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

You can also use `::testing::FLAGS_gmock_catch_leaked_mocks = false;` to switch off all gmock leak detection, but this is probably a bad habit to get into.  It may be appropriate in this case however if you have a large number of mock objects when you call `exit()`.  It's also worth switching it back on immediately after `EXPECT_DEATH` in case the test goes on to do further work (although in your example above, it's pointless to switch it back on).

```
TEST(BDeathTest,BDies) {
    MockA * a = new MockA;
    ON_CALL(*a,bla(_)).WillByDefault(Return(1));
    B * b = new B(a);
    FLAGS_gmock_catch_leaked_mocks = false;  // <=== Switch off mock leak checking
    EXPECT_DEATH(b->kill(),"");
    FLAGS_gmock_catch_leaked_mocks = true;  // <=== Re-enable mock leak checking
                                            //      in case the test is refactored
    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

Finally, a third way to handle this particular case is to `delete a_;` in `B::kill()` rather than allowing it to leak.

```
class B {
    ...
    void kill() {
        delete a_;
        exit(1);
    }
    MockA * a_;
};

TEST(BDeathTest,BDies) {
    MockA * a = new MockA;
    ON_CALL(*a,bla(_)).WillByDefault(Return(1));
    B * b = new B(a);
    EXPECT_DEATH(b->kill(),"");
    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

Since gtest spawns a new process to execute the death test, you're safe to delete `a_` just before `exit`ing while also deleting `a` inside the test fixture.

However, to someone who doesn't know how gtest death tests work, this would look like the same variable getting deleted twice, and could cause confusion.

Comment: the question is: why does googlemock check for deleted things at the end of the death test, isn't this a bug?

Comment: I don't think so.  gmock probably isn't even aware that the destruction of its objects is in the context of a gtest death test.  Also, a death test could be testing for a graceful application exit too, where objects are properly deleted.  Defaulting to checking for leaks seems to be gmock's best option, particularly since you can explicitly disable this behaviour if required.